# Flags - show a flag marker even if user cannot modify it

Tags: flags

I have been able to set up a flag with Advanced forum to allow users to mark comment in  a thread they started as an accepted answer. It was simple to set up and works well.

However, it seems [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) only alters a comment if the user has permissions to set/unset the flag. I want a tick to appear on a comment which has been flagged which any (even anonymous) users should be able to see. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new boolean field *Answer* to comments which has a default value of 0. Next, create a Rule that changes the boolean value of a flagged comment to 1. The rest is theming; use the following code in your comment.tpl.php file:

```
<?php if ($comment->field_answer['und'][0]['value']): ?>
  <mark>This is the answer</mark>
<?php endif; ?>
```